# Migration of racktables mysql database to Azure Mysql database

Tags: azure-mysql-database

i created the dump of the original on-prem database. And am trying to import it into Azure mysql.
the execution of sql statements fails on
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`racktablesuser`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `Link-before-update`
It appears i dont have enough permissions to run the command with DEFINER parameter. I searched online and found that Azure is not allowing any DB user to have super user rights.

I tried to run the sql statements without DEFINER but all views created this way are not accessable by the application.

Any idea how this could be solved?